# Using preprocessor macro to decide if app build is for debug or release

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, xcode5, nslog

I want to log some events for debug builds. I have added below code in .pch file to log using `DLog()` in debug only. I have added `IS_DEBUG` macro in build setting.

```
#ifdef IS_DEBUG
    #define DLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define DLog(...)
#endif
```

To test if it works or not, I removed `IS_DEBUG` from build setting and ran app. Issue is that it always logs irrespective of debug/release app.

Please note that I tried changing the name of both `DLog`method and preprocessor macro to see it is due to same macro or method is defined somewhere else. But still it gives same issue, means same macro or method is not used else where.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bryan's answer helped me in solving this issue. Only cleaning project and Xcode cache did not work for me. I reset the simulator and cleaned project. It got it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode you are able to define Schemes. Each scheme can build to a specific configuration, usually at least Debug and Release. You can specify which you would like to use in the scheme manager in Xcode.

Next, in your targets configuration, you can change the macros that are defined for which configuration you'd like it to be associated with. In your case this would be 'IS_DEBUG'. Most likely you'd want to do this for the Debugging configtation, then create a scheme to build that configuration.

Comment: But when I have removed the macro then it should not log the values. No matter it is debug or release.

Comment: I would first check to make sure that there are not any direct calls to NSLog. If not that would mean that IS_DEBUG must be set somewhere else.

Comment: @Brayn I used DLog(). As mentioned in question, I have tried renaming macro and method name both. So if IS_DEBUG is defined else where, renaming a macro should work. But it does not.

Comment: That is strange. I have come across weird Xcode bugs in the past and this may be one of them. Have you tried clearing the build output? Maybe that would help. Also, clear the Xcode cache. Use this command in a terminal:

Comment: sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*